# text-overflow change content of ellipsis

Tags: html, css

A customer sent me a font where the '...'-character is not defined (it only shows up a mirror-inverted '3'). So i wanted to do something like:

```
.myclass ul li{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow-content: '...';
}
```

any idea, how I can do this?

Comment: Instead of specifying `ellipsis` as the value, just use `text-overflow: "..."` (three periods `.`). However, textual/string content for the `text-overflow` value has limited support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You *can* set the value of [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to a string, like:

```
.myclass ul li{
    text-overflow: '...';
}
```

However:

- It has horrible browser support(Only in Firefox and maybe edge)
- It's only [specified in the editors draft for CSS](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#text-overflow), so it could very well be removed/changed.

In the draft, it even says:

> Note: The `<string>` value, and the 2-value syntax `"{1,2}"` and functionality are all at risk.

#### Basically, *don't use the string value*.

Because of this, I'd just use a class if the overflow doesn't have to be dynamic, or JS if it does.

**JS Solution**

```js
let p = document.querySelector(".js-overflow");

// Add overflow class if needed
if (p.scrollWidth > p.offsetWidth) p.classList.add("has-overflow");

while (p.scrollWidth > p.offsetWidth) {
  // Remove characters from paragraph until the text and the overflow indicator fit
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
}
```

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  /* BOTH of the following are required for text-overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.has-overflow:after {
  content: "..."
}
```

```html
<p class="js-overflow">
  Simple string to test text overflow, will overflow to your custom string at 200px.
</p>
```

A JS solution is quite simple:

1. Check if the elements scroll width is wider than it's actual width(meaning it has an overflow)
2. Loop, removing the last character until the scroll width *with* the `after` pseudo elements content is less than the width.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, where the ellipsis character is malformed or missing, you could alternatively set up a custom font face that will allow you to use a different font for just that one ellipsis character:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "ellipsis-font";

  /*
   * Change this to whatever font you want.
   * It's Courier here to make it clear it changed from the default
   */
  src: local("Courier");

  /*
   * The unicode for ellipsis ("…").
   * Makes it so this font only gets applied for that single character
   */
  unicode-range: U+2026;
}

.my-container {
  width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /*
   * Putting our custom font in the front ensures
   * it handles the ellipsis display, the second font
   * in line should handle everything else
   */
  font-family: ellipsis-font, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">This is some lengthy text that is bound to get cut off by overflow</div>
```