# replace ... with read more ( customize elipses )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with fixed height and width but the content of the div is dynamic.

I want to replace **...** with **...read more** only when elipses is active.

Any javascript code to achieve this?

**CODE**

```js
document.getElementById("read-more").onclick = function(){
 this.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
}
```

```css
div#read-more{
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 48px auto 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>Resize your browser window to see what happens to the text in the box below. When the text is too long, an ellipse is added to the end.</p>
<div id="read-more">Lorem ipsum dolor. Sit in your comfy office chair and OOH and AHH at the cool ellipsis!</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aw6zf0be/)**

Comment: `text-overflow: '... read more';` (or `…read more` if you want) - [Read The Fine Manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: height: 30px; You don't declare height value !

Comment: @NikolaLukic You don't need to declare a height as the auto cut-off is only horizontal here,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-overflow change content of ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549021/text-overflow-change-content-of-ellipsis)

Answer (score 1):

For now only firefox seem to have the such effect if you play with

```
text-overflow: '...readmore';
```

Other browser dont respond to it.

Another solution would be to

```js
var p = document.querySelector(".js-overflow");

if (p.scrollWidth > p.offsetWidth) p.classList.add("has-overflow");

while (p.scrollWidth > p.offsetWidth) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
}
```

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  /* BOTH of the following are required for text-overflow */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.has-overflow:after {
  content: "...readmore"
}
```

```html
<p class="js-overflow">
  Testing overflow yaya look at me !
</p>
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549021/text-overflow-change-content-of-ellipsis#)

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda X already commented use `text-overflow: '... read more';`

```js
document.getElementById("read-more").onclick = function() {
  this.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
}
```

```css
div#read-more {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 48px auto 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '…read more';
}
```

```html
<p>Resize your browser window to see what happens to the text in the box below. When the text is too long, an ellipse is added to the end.</p>
<div id="read-more">Lorem ipsum dolor. Sit in your comfy office chair and OOH and AHH at the cool ellipsis!</div>
```