# Add dot dot dot without using ellipsis in css

Tags: html, css, less

I am working in an app using Japanese and the ellipsis is awkward when using a specific font-family and `text-overflow: ellipsis`. I do not want to change the language or the font family, but I need to add '...' at the end when overflow hidden occurs.

As you can see in the next picture, `text-overflow: ellipsis` gives a strange ellipsis when using `lang='ja'` and a `font-family: 'Meiryo', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN', 'MS PGothic', sans-serif;`.

[image]

I tried:

```
   text-overflow: '...';
   overflow: hidden;
```

but it only works in Firefox and not in Chrome.

I also tried
`style.less`

```
  .myClass {
   overflow: hidden;
   &::after {
      content: '...';
      }
  }
```

But I cannot see the dots at the end. Also I think this approach will not work because it will still show when I the overflow does not occur.

Is there a way to solve this problem and show '...' without using `text-overflow: ellipsis` property?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would likely be not robust to reimplement your own version of an ellipsis replacement without careful consideration. Instead, you should still use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but change the the font used specifically for drawing the ellipsis.

You can import a subset of a font with an ellipsis you like. Some font APIs like Google Fonts may offer the choice of specific characters— but be careful not to let a cached version of the font get used in place of the subset version on users' browsers that already loaded the full font from another website. You could, for example, request the subset from Google Fonts then download that file and serve it yourself instead of using their API. There are other tools available for subsetting font files as well.

Set that font, with only a single character code point, to the primary font. Then use your existing Japanese font as the second font in the list, so every character except the ellipsis falls back to that.

```css
font-family: EllipsisOnly, OriginalFont, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Check this answer for more details about implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549021/text-overflow-change-content-of-ellipsis#answer-74869360

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `line-clamp` for this if you are looking for an alternative to `ellipsis`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.container a {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">https://www.google.com/search?q=test&sxsrf=AJOqlzWNoUUAOimgD4A3hBszbmaNaPgnVw%3A1673411070272&source=hp&ei=_jm-Y5q-Deys5NoPprGNoAs&iflsig=AK50M_UAAAAAY75IDtpFnzh-ep_zI64uvq-ypac-DtRk&ved=0ahUKEwiatZ2D1r78AhVsFlkFHaZYA7QQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=test&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEJECMgQIABBDMgoIABCxAxCDARBDMgQIABBDMgoIABCxAxCDARBDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBMggIABCABBCxAzIFCAAQgAQ6BwgjEOoCECc6BAgjECc6BAguEEM6EAguELEDEIMBEMcBENEDEENQxAFYtgRgggdoAXAAeACAAdwCiAGYCpIBAzMtNJgBAKABAbABCg&sclient=gws-wiz</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way it can work without setting the width and just using all the available space?

Comment: @programandoconro you can remove the width and it will still work the same way

Comment: Sorry, not working for my example. But thanks for your answer, it may help in different scenario.